# rJava: Creating zero-length Java arrays from R

Tags: java, arrays, r, java-native-interface, rjava

I am looking for the [rJava](https://www.rforge.net/rJava/#types) equivalent of:

```
String[] s;
s= new String[0];
```

I tried:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
s=.jarray(list(NULL), "[Ljava/lang/String;")
```

But when passing it to a method expecting a `String[]` with `jcall(..., s)`, rJava raises an error.

### Update

To make my question clearer.
I could, of course, easily make a new jar (or modifying the existing one for) hosting some `zeroArray()` method to be later called from R, but I am looking for a solution *based on rJava*, which means using standard Java objects or the classes in jar files shipped by rJava or internal rJava functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have something like this:

```
package utils;

public class RUsingStringArray {

        public void useArray(String [] array) {
          for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++ ) {
            String str = array[i];
          }
        }
        public int arrayLen(String [] array) {
                System.out.println("Class: " + array.getClass());
                return array.length;
        }
        public String [] createArray() {
                return new String[0];
        }
        public static void main(String [] arg) {

                RUsingStringArray obj = new RUsingStringArray();
                obj.useArray(obj.createArray());
                System.out.println("Len: " + obj.arrayLen(new String[0]) );
        }
}
```

method, createArray will return

```
> obj <- .jnew("utils.RUsingStringArray")
> s <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="[Ljava/lang/String;", method="createArray")
> s
character(0)
```

and you can use it as empty String [] later on

```
.jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method = "useArray", s)
```

Of course, this one will work as well

```
> b <- character(0)
> .jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method = "useArray", b)
```

Question is, whether this is something you are looking for.

**Update:**

In that case, maybe this is something better in your case?

```
> array <- .jarray(list(NULL), "java/lang/String")
> .jcall(obj, returnSig="V", method="useArray", array)
```

**Update2:**

How about this one ;)

```
> array2 <- .jarray(character(0), "java/lang/String")
> .jcall(obj, returnSig="I", method="arrayLen", array2)
Class: class [Ljava.lang.String;
[1] 0
>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am actually looking for an rJava solution.  I made this point clearer in the post update. Sorry if this was not clear in the beginning.

Comment: Testing with: `public int useArray (String[] ar ) {return ar.length ;}` and calling `.jcall(obj, returnSig="I", method="useArray", array)` returns `1`, while it should be `0` if `String[] array=new String[0];`.

Comment: .oOo. yet another one, from my side ;) .oOo.

Comment: Great! and apparently simple after you know the sol)